# AND, OR conditions in if statement

Tags: shell, unix, if-statement, conditional-statements

i have the following code

```
elif [ $text2 == 'LANDING' ] && [ "$text4" == 'FAIL' ] || [ "$text4" == '' ]; then
```

the condition is that text2 should be landing and text4 can either be fail or null.
How to evaluate the above command.

Please help if Im doing any wrong 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to group them explicitly:

```
elif  [ "$text2" = 'LANDING' ] &&
      { [ "$text4" = 'FAIL' ] || [ "$text4" = '' ]; }; then
```

Your attempt would succeed either of the following two conditions held:

1. `text2` was LANDING *and* `text4` was FAIL
2. `text4` was empty or unset.

Since `&&` and `||` have the same precedence, you could (perhaps surprisingly) write it without grouping:

```
elif [ "$text4" = '' ] || [ "$text4" = FAIL ] && [ $text2 == 'LANDING' ]; then
```

If you are using `bash`, you can use the `[[ ... ]]` command instead of `[ ... ]`. The grouping is required; the operators inside `[[ ... ]]` *do* have the precedences you would expect from other languages (that is, `a || b && c` is `a || (b && c)`, not `(a || b) && c`).

```
elif [[ $text2 == 'LANDING' && ( "$text4" == 'FAIL' || "$text4" == '') ]]; then
```

Answer (score 1):

Not particular recommended, but with bash, you can use extended globbing patterns in `[[...]]`

```
elif [[ $text2 == 'LANDING' && $text4 == @(FAIL|) ]]; then
```

Answer (score 0):

Use curly braces or parentheses to group the `||` operands together. Parentheses look nicer, but they create a subshell which is inefficient, so curly braces are the way to go even though they're ugly.

```
elif [ $text2 == 'LANDING' ] && { [ "$text4" == 'FAIL' ] || [ "$text4" == '' ]; }; then
```

Notice that the curly braces require an extra semicolon.

Alternatively, if you're using bash you could use double square brackets, which allow for the slightly prettier:

```
elif [[ $text2 == 'LANDING' && ("$text4" == 'FAIL' || "$text4" == '') ]]; then
```